# Code snippet button overlap on suggested edit review

Tags: bug, review-queues, design, suggested-edits

The code snippet UI is bugged when reviewing suggested edits in side-by-side view.

The "Hide results" and "Full page" elements overlap after a snippet is run.

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30638114)

Screenshot showing bug:

[image: Screenshot showing bug]